# How to handle timeout error in request.head(url)?

Tags: python, python-requests

Script:

```
>>> import requests
>>> print(requests.head('https://knoema.com/BISDPPLS2016/bis-property-prices-long-series'))
<Response [200]>

>>> print(requests.head('https://beta.knoema.org/BISDPPLS2016/bis-property-prices-long-series'))
Connection to beta.knoema.org timed out.
```

I tried below as well, but same error:

```
>>> print(requests.head('https://beta.knoema.org/IRFCL2016Jul', timeout=5))
```

I want to stop `requests.head(url)` if it does not exist or is not loading for any reason. How to achieve this?

Comment: You should use try - except block with requests exceptions. Here is documentation for this... http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/exceptions/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to handle exception using [try-catch](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#errors-and-exceptions)

```
try: 
    requests.head('https://beta.knoema.org/BISDPPLS2016/bis-property-prices-long-series')
except requests.exceptions.Timeout as e:
    print e
```

Also you can set a large timeout to avoid error due to slow connection

```
requests.head('https://beta.knoema.org/BISDPPLS2016/bis-property-prices-long-series', \
               timeout=5)
```

Here timeout is 5 seconds